# Android optimize query on ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Is there a way to speed up the query for a contentresolver? I find querying for contacts takes a bit of time even with a proper projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask for fewer columns in the projection. Better yet, ask for fewer rows in the result set.

You can also use Traceview to confirm that the time truly is in the query itself, versus anything you are doing with the resulting `Cursor`.

Comment: Also, perform the query asynchronously, for example by using an `AsyncTask` or the new `CursorLoader`, if you aren't doing so already. This will not necessarily speed up the query itself, but it will provide a better experience (the UI won't lag).